# Large MySQL Database with Small Data

Tags: mysql, database

I am designing a database that will be based around a group progress quiz. The quiz consists of 55 questions, and ideally a group of 10 people will take the quiz every few weeks, each person taking it once for everyone in the group, including themselves. So, each time the group takes the quiz, 100 pieces of data will be added to the database.

Currently my table for storing the quiz answers will have the following rows:

```
quiz_taker_id      // person taking the quiz
quiz_subject_id    // taker is answering questions about this person
quiz_id            // identifies if this is the 1st time taking the quiz, 2nd time, etc
question1          // answer to question 1
question2          // answer to question 2
...                // etc, for all quiz questions
```

The quiz answers are incredibly simple, its just a ration of 0-5 on a person's characteristics. Is this a good way to be storing this data? Are there better ways to do this? I am just starting to set up the website and DB, so I want to make sure I am approaching this the right way

Comment: What are you going to do with this data? What kind of queries are you going to run against it?

Comment: @PM77-1 asks the right question - in most cases, if it is possible, you are better off designing your database schema based on how you want to report on/query against the data. Many people would say a "better"design would be to further normalize your data, but it may or may not be worthwhile based on how you intend to use it and what you expect the life of the app to be. If this is (e.g.) for a specific study you plan to run for a few months, what you have may be perfectly suitable.

Comment: The quiz goes along with a self-help book. At the end, each group member ranks each other in 55 different personality categories, then a few weeks later they all rank each other again. This will continue indefinitely, but I can probably start deleting old data after the 10th quiz.

Comment: The data wont be used very much, an individual person should be able to check a progress list, and the data will then be used to see how they have progressed over time.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to process data in any way (like make postgame stats) it is a good idea to use databases. Your db design is very simple and lacks some flexibility, like say, you want to add more questions later (now you have to add extra column).

So it really depends on what you plan to do with the collected data and if you plan to extend your quiz rules.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

The questions should be in a single table, `questions` not one table per question. A basic questions table would have each question and its correct answer.  This is probably good enough for your problem.

For surveys (and for quizzes, I imagine), there is a versioning problem, because questions can slowly change over time.  As a somewhat trivial example, you might start start by asking "What is your gender?" and initially offer two answers "Male", "Female".  Over time, you might start adding additional other answers:  "Other", "Transsexual", "Hermaphrodite" and so on.  When analyzing the answers, you might need to know the version of the question that was asked at a particular time.

This is a survey example, where there is no right answer, but a similar idea applies to quizzes:  the questions and answers might evolve somewhat over time, but you still want them to be recognized at Question 2, but you want to know the version being asked.